# ¿Por qué no funciona el código de retardo en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, while

Tengo el siguiente código con un retardo de 4 segundos (4000), pero no funciona porque inmediatamente sale el `alert` (también disponible en [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/xudawodemi/edit?html,js,console,output)):

```js
esperar_mSeg(4000);
alert("TODO BIEN");

function esperar_mSeg(_) {
  _ += new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date() < _) {}
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué desea hacer? ¿Cuál el propósito de su código?

Comment: el retardo de 4 segundos (4000) no funciona... inmediatamente sale el Alert,,,, lo puedes comprobar en el enlace de JSBIN

Comment: Estas comparando un date con un number. Probablemente querias `while (new Date().getTime() < _){}`

Comment: He puesto el código de arriba como ejecutable y funciona bien: el `alert` no sale hasta unos 4 segundos después de darle a ejecutar.

Comment: Otra cosa es que no es una buena idea tener ese tipo de retrasos (porque te van a bloquear la ejecución y/o pueden ser de un tiempo diferente al esperado), pero eso ya es otro tema.

Comment: Por cierto, el enlace a JSBin no parece estar relacionado con la pregunta. ¿Quizás sea un enlace equivocado?